# PHP | Performance of ascending vs descending loops

Tags: php, performance

Recently I heard that descending FOR loops works faster than ascending. I was wondering why and didnt found any documented confirmations. I decided to make following tests:

```
<?php

$a = null;

$limit = pow(10, 9);

$time = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
    $a = 1;
}

$time = microtime(true) - $time;

echo "Asc " . number_format($time, 3) . PHP_EOL;

$a = null;

$time = microtime(true);

for ($i = $limit; $i > 0; --$i) {
    $a = 1;
}

$time = microtime(true) - $time;

echo "Desc " . number_format($time, 3) . PHP_EOL;
```

I was really surprised when had different results -
Asc 84.365
Desc 64.448

Could you tell me what I did wrong in test or why descending loop is actually faster?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you run the test again with the descending loop first?

Comment: When I tried results are almost same. Sometimes observed descending took bit more time.

Comment: I can confirm the descending is faster but not that much as you got. Tested on Ubuntu 18 and W10 for PHP 7.3

Comment: @Vindic my test was on OS X 10.13, PHP 7.0.33

Comment: @Nick almost same results